# Yum on CentOS 6 upgrading hundreds of packages?

Tags: centos6, yum, upgrade

I do yum updates very frequently, almost daily. I was doing a normal yum update just now and I am being asked to update a large number of packages:

```
Install      12 Package(s)
Upgrade     315 Package(s)
Remove        2 Package(s)
```

This seems more than a little strange and have not come across this in some time. Normally my updates are somewhere in the ballpark of one or two.

Is this something I should be concerned about? I would suspect something more fundamental could be wrong here but I don't know where to start. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new release of CentOS just came out a few days ago.  It's not surprising that there's a sudden influx of new packages.